# Error loading XCTest, no suitable image found.

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode6, xctest, kif

I have recently updated my Xcode and started having this error.

```
2014-11-03 15:03:54.222 App[13141:60b] Error loading /private/var/mobile/Applications/677127BD-5230-4D5F-B70E-AF728439D34B/tmp/AppTests.xctest/AppTests:  dlopen(/private/var/mobile/Applications/677127BD-5230-4D5F-B70E-AF728439D34B/tmp/AppTests.xctest/AppTests, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Applications/677127BD-5230-4D5F-B70E-AF728439D34B/tmp/AppTests.xctest/AppTests: code signature invalid for '/private/var/mobile/Applications/677127BD-5230-4D5F-B70E-AF728439D34B/tmp/AppTests.xctest/AppTests'
DevToolsBundleInjection: Error loading bundle '/private/var/mobile/Applications/677127BD-5230-4D5F-B70E-AF728439D34B/tmp/AppTests.xctest'
```

I have done my Google search as usual. But I haven't found any solutions yet. Source I have looked and tried to resolve my issue with is,

1. http://marcschwieterman.com/blog/testing-in-the-sandbox/

**When it happens?**

It only shows this error if I run uni test on device. On simulator it works as expected. Running application from normal target does not show this error.

**When error shows up while running Uni Test app does not crash. It just fails to load xctests.**

Anyone having similar issues? and manage to resolve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378922/xctest-test-failed

Comment: @matt, It would be better if you can explain. As I have already linked my effort so far...and you have given me the same link again. Except yours is via a Stackoverflow. Also, I am running test on device so code has to be signed as far as I know.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've encountered exactly the same problem. I was able to fix the problem by setting the provisioning profile to something other than Automatic on both targets (the test and the test host).

I verified this was the problem by reverting it back to automatic, and the problem reoccured.

Comment: Yup that solved the issue...It is definitely a bug in XCode. Thanks Mate!

Comment: I tried to set the same provisioning profile for both the app and the xctest bundle but I still got the same invalid signature error. I tried with _iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *_, maybe it works with  a provisioning profile with a full bundle identifier…

Comment: Had this error, I had to set both targets provisioning profile to a wildcard profile.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 10 here.

For me the issue was the discrepancy between the Project deployment target and the Target deployment target. Once I had them matching, XCTest started working.

Comment: The problem for me was almost the same: the deployment target of the tests target was higher than the iOS version of the simulator that I was trying to use.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

@tagy22's comment worked for me

> Had this error, I had to set both targets provisioning profile to a wildcard profile.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I deleted all iOS developer certificates from OS X keychain and the iPhone developer portal, and then let Xcode re-request the development certificates, the problem is resolved.