# Xcode 7 Can't run a test on the device, Fatal error occurs

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, xctest

I try to run a simple test.
Everything is fine in the simulator, when i run on the device, emerge   following error:
[image]

The Log is "dyld: could not load inserted library '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7EE29748-5E86-4E9B-B8E5-882753654F87/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7EE29748-5E86-4E9B-B8E5-882753654F87/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection: code signature invalid for '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7EE29748-5E86-4E9B-B8E5-882753654F87/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection'
"

I tried to make Clean & Build and remove derived data, it didn't help me.

I appreciate any tips or helps

Comment: Potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956390/xcode-5-tests-not-running

Comment: Nope, this one is not related. Looks different and the accepted solution doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a Scheme that does a Release build? If so, try a Debug build instead.

Comment: @Kesava I've solved that, the cause was a migration of developer account settings from xCode6 to xCode7. It required  to reload all provision profiles into account setting of xCode7 for correct validation. Apple's provided a new profile as free independent developer, by this reason perhaps there was emerge a critical error.

Comment: @kokos8998 is right => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707792/error-loading-xctest-no-suitable-image-found

Comment: Thanks for posting the question! Just had the same problem. That error message from Xcode is incredibly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

This was due to me changing my appleID password. If you sign back in Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts, this fixes the problem.

Comment: As I said, there is a some conflict among accounts into Preferences settings

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for the whole afternoon and finally found my solution. Yes it is about the certificates again.

I heard the news that Apple's world developer relations certificate expired but never realized it'll become a problem until now.

In my keychain all the developer identifies appeared with the red status as "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority".

So the solutions is, go to http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ and download "Worldwide Developer Relations - G2 Certificate", import it into your keychain, check the status of your developer identity certificate and if it turns green (valid), the unit testing problem should be fixed.